# Is the word "unwavering" used as a positive or a negative meaning?

Tags: word-meaning

I check it on the dictionary, and it says that attitude ,belief, expression does not change.So I do not understand whether it means positive or negative or
it depends on the context.

For example,'A child has unwavering belief in him'.
I take it both a positive and a negative meaning,
It is a good thing to believe in themselves,
but having too much confidence in probably leads to downside.

Comment: That depends on the context. Positive or negative, the "attitude, etc." is just not changing. Adding an example to your question might help.

Comment: What kind of belief? Who is *him*?

Answer (score 1):

Agreeing with V.V. that although "un" is typical negative, many times "unwavering" is used positively.

I would even say that those in the U.S. think of and use this word mostly in a positive manner, meaning the person is determined and won't let anyone or anything deter him/her from their goal.

Some common uses are...

> 1. She is unwavering in her faith.
>      (meaning she will not let anything pull her away from God)
> 2. I'm sorry, but I cannot do what you're asking.  This is unethical.  I will not waver in my decision.
>      (here we use "will not waiver")

However, when we want something that someone is not giving us, we could use the word in a negative context.

> 3. COWORKER 1:  My manager is very tight with the budget and will not let me purchase a second monitor.  COWORKER 2:  Have you tried telling her how much more productive you will be?  COWORKER 1:  Yes, but she is unwavering in her decision.  I'm wasn't able to change her mind.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your clear explanation! I understand perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Although "un-" is negative, the meaning doesn't necessarily depend on the word but on the context. In your example (and in most cases) it is positive "steady".